# Assign a numerical print to a real number value holder. Then store that real number value

Tags: fortran, gfortran

Below, where it says " print *, "What is the distance" , the answer to that will be a number that includes a decimal. I want that answer to be stored in a variable/data type that will be later used to perform a calculation. This is written with fortran95 (.f95).

The code:

```
program Artillecal
implicit none
character*20 :: terrain_type

print *, "Type of Terrain: Plain, Mountain, Hill"
read *, terrain_type
print *, terrain_type

if ((terrain_type) == "Plain" .or. (terrain_type) == "Mountain" .or. (terrain_type) == "Hill") then
    print *, "What is the distance"
    
end if
end program Artillecal
```

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do. Are you just trying to read in a number in response to the question "What is the distance"?

Comment: Looks like a homework problem? The title says "... real number holder". You probably want to consider a variable to recieve, or hold, the value?

Comment: Why has this been closed as a duplicate? It is not at all obvious that this is what the OP is asking, and it is not at all obvious that the answer linked to (which I wrote) provides what the OP needs.

Comment: @IanBush, the question asker closed the question (in response to a proposed duplicate flag). I also don't agree it's a useful duplicate, but I assume the person asking the question knows whether the linked question was "helpful". (I won't vote to reopen because I don't think we can answer the question without further information.)